# How to cite my own report that hasn't been published?

Tags: citations

I wrote a research paper in high school in the field of lasers and optics but did not get published. It is on the internet open for anyone to read. How should I go on citing this? I want to refer to it in an application where it asks me to cite all works I have been a part of.

Comment: I'd say, if it is on the Internet, it's published. It's not peer-reviewed, but that's another point.

Answer (score 2):

If you create a profile on researchgate you can upload your work and it gives you a citation. It also gives you your own personal dio code so that you can cross reference your work with other sites. This is what I have used. Here is the web site: www.researchgate.net

Additionally you can also create a google scholar profile sync your work from researchgate and it automatically gives you a citation.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question -- what's a dio code?

Comment: I think he ment DOI code. It's a special hyperlink used for scientific papers.

That being said, I would **not** recommend researchgate. Many people view it as the Linked-in of academia, and reserve a special kind of hate for it. The arXiv is a much more universally-liked platform.

Answer (score 2):

Exactly the same way you'd cite something miscellaneous written by somebody else. If it is on the 'web, give the complete URL (and see if you can make sure it won't go away, stash away a personal copy for safekeeping).